# how does a program know where it's shared libs are, without LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have a program `foobar` that uses shared libraries. I setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly and then when I run

```
>ldd foobar
```

I can see that it knows full paths to all the libraries it needs.

However, on some systems ("bigger" ones), I don't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `ldd` to know where the libraries are, and on some ("smaller" ones) I do.

On both systems, the executable `foobar` is the same, the path to it is the same, and all the libraries and paths to them are the same.

So that means, the `rpath` built into the executable, is the same in both cases.

So there must be some other way to determine where the libraries are?  What is it?

Answer (score 0):

The /lib and /usr/lib are added automatically. Other libraries are added from the /etc/ld.so.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

`ldconfig` is a utility that maintains a cache of shared libraries.  When properly configured, the right library paths will be cached and available to the executives.  You can use `ldconfig -p` to print the currently available library candidates.

See the manpage for `ldconfig(8)`.